# Understanding the saving of Methods into Objects in Java

Tags: java, oop

In the javadoc there is an example of code in the class Pattern, which I do not understand regarding to the concept.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

- The compile method is static and gets saved into an object of the class Pattern. How does that work?
- The method matcher gets called from the object of the instance p and gets stored into a variable of the type Matcher. How does that work?

Comment: What do you mean by “gets saved into an object of the class Pattern”?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating it a bit here. The methods return a `Pattern` and `Matcher` respectively, just as the `matches` method returns a boolean and `Math.sqrt` returns a double.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The question is about what gets saved in the variable `p`. I don't understand why you can assign the output from a static method to the variable of an instance of a class.

Comment: It doesn't matter at all that the method is static. It is a method which returns an object of type Pattern.

Comment: A static method is really just a method decoupled from the state of an object. It doesn't mean it can't instantiate objects itself, otherwise a static method would probably have no use.

Comment: Think of Pattern.compile() as a factory method. It returns an instance of a Pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to look at the Java source code in your IDE / [online](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java). Thus, lets go through what's really happening here:

```java
public static Pattern compile(String regex) {
    return new Pattern(regex, 0);
}
```

The static `compile` method doesn't actually compile or "save anything to the class", it just creates a new `Pattern` instance for you and returns it.

---

```java
private Pattern(String p, int f) {
    //...
}
```

The `Pattern` class's constructor is `private`, meaning that you're not able to instantiate it yourself directly; meaning that you have to use `Pattern.compile` and friends.

---

**Q:** Why did they design it this way??

The main idea is that the constructor they've got going on is a bit weird --- it takes in that flags int, and constructors in other classes in the standard library are worse, to the point where you might need quite in-depth knowledge of the class's inner workings in order to use them. So, it can make sense to move those to being private implementation details, and then make a few methods which create your class correctly for all the use cases people need, and to be reasonably consistent with how you do it.